# Unit gunicorn.service failed to load: No such file or directory

Tags: server

When setting up a new Ubuntu 15.10 x64 server running nginx, gunicorn, django as a sudo user. I am getting an  error message by running `sudo service gunicorn start`:

```
Failed to start gunicorn.service: 
Unit gunicorn.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

From an active virtualenv I can start gunicorn using:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated on how to resolve this as I have tried quite a few suggestions from various web searches that mentioned problems similar to this with no luck.

My gunicorn file is at `/etc/init/gunicorn.conf` and is configured as follows:

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid myuser
setgid www-data
chdir /home/myuser/myproject

exec myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/myuser/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
```

Comment: `/etc/init/gunicorn.conf` is in Upstart configuration, suitable for 14.04 and 12.04. 15.10 uses systemd, so you'll have to write a systemd unit. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers

Comment: Thank you very much for assistance, this worked great. I added "/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service" file and this works great.

Comment: Excellent! Can you post the unit file you used, for future visitors?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create `gunicorn.service` in `/etc/systemd/system`.
Next, add this code to it and replace `user` , `myproject` and `myprojectenv` accordingly.

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/myproject
ExecStart=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: hi i cannot add file to the /etc/systemd/system