# "gunicorn: unrecognized service" on Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: server, 15.10

I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04) to setup Django with Gunicorn, but ran into a problem where Ubuntu 15.10 uses systemd instead of upstart. So after asking a [question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749135/unit-gunicorn-service-failed-to-load-no-such-file-or-directory-on-ubuntu-15-1) to figure that out, I found [another guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7) for CentOS to help me configure systemd.

With that in mind, I came up with the following gunicorn.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/webapps/games
ExecStart=/home/webapps/games/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/webapps/games/games.sock games.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I set the group/user to root just to make sure permissions are causing problems temporarily. The directory structure is as follows at `/home/webapps/games`

```
├── games
│   └── wsgi.py
├── venv
│   └── bin
│       └── gunicorn
└── manage.py
```

When I try to run `service gunicorn start` I get a cryptic error `gunicorn: unrecognized service`. I'm not sure where to go from here and I can't find any logs either. Any ideas?

When running this from the command line `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application` it works as expected and serves files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on ubuntu then it I don't think that CentOS instructions will work. Taken from DigitalOcean tutorial you should create .conf file for upstart:

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setude user
setgid www-data
chdir /home/webapps

exec /home/webapps/games/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/webapps/games/games.sock games.wsgi:application
```

## Notes

1. user should be user owning the environment and the project and for group his group.
2. File should live in /etc/init/gunicorn.conf.
3. Log files for upstart gunicorn would be in /var/log/upstart/gunicorn.conf

you

Comment: Thank you for this, but the problem is that upstart has been removed with Ubuntu 15.10, and that is why I had to move to default systemd and the CentOS configuration. However, I can't imagine the configuration being that different for a specific application, but maybe an expert can chime in.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install upstart` also in your links for centOS `sudo systemctl start unicorn` is used not service