# Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found. Ubunto 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) How To Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 18.04 guide.

**I have created the following file .socket**

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**I have created the following file .service**

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

**Original RECOMENDED_FORMATTING-s in the [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04)**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target


[Service]
User=sammyRECOMENDED_FORMATTING
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammyRECOMENDED_FORMATTING/myprojectdirRECOMENDED_FORMATTING
ExecStart=/home/sammyRECOMENDED_FORMATTING/myprojectdirRECOMENDED_FORMATTING/myprojectenvRECOMENDED_FORMATTING/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myprojectRECOMENDED_FORMATTING.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**How I have formatted my own version** I had my virtual environment outside of the project folder on the server

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=SERVER_USER
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/SERVER_USER/MAIN_PROJECT_FOLDER
ExecStart=/home/SERVER_USER/ven/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/home/SERVER_USER/MAIN_PROJECT_FOLDER/MAINAPPLICATION_FOLDER.sock \
          MAINAPPLICATION_FOLDER.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**I have also tried leaving these as originally recommended**

`--bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \`

**Than I have tried to execute the following code**

`sudo systemctl start gunicorn`

**error message 1**

`Failed to start gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service not found.`

**and I have also tried with 2**

`sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket`

**Error message 2**

```
Failed to start gunicorn.socket: Unit gunicorn.socket is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status gunicorn.socket' for details.
```

**To solve this, I have tried**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711747/failed-to-start-gunicorn-service-unit-gunicorn-service-not-found This points back to the exact same guide that I am doing except with an older version of linux.
- this is not the same code and not answered [Unit gunicorn.service failed to load: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748836/unit-gunicorn-service-failed-to-load-no-such-file-or-directory)
- Run: `systemctl status gunicorn.socket` Result: `Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of gunicorn.socket changed on disk
  ● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn daemon
  Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
  Active: inactive (dead)`
- Run: `systemctl is-enabled gunicorn.socket` Result: `enabled`
- Run: `systemctl is-enabled gunicorn.service` Result: `Failed to get unit file state for gunicorn.service: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can you check the unit files with `systemctl list-unit-files | grep gunicorn`

Comment: Also to start a socket related service you have to do `sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket` which will start the service also

Comment: CODE run: ```systemctl list-unit-files | grep gunicorn``` reults```gunicorn.socket                        disabled    ```

Comment: I have tried that one ```sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket``` as well and posted the error message in to my main post

Comment: To enable socket run `sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket` the to check if both is enabled run thje commands `systemctl  is-enabled gunicorn.socket` and `systemctl is-enabled gunicorn.service` . You did not mention creating the gunicorn socket anywhere.

Comment: ```systemctl is-enabled gunicorn.socket``` result ```enabled``` and for the other one ```systemctl is-enabled gunicorn.service``` result: ```Failed to get unit file state for gunicorn.service: No such file or directory```

Comment: These commands ```sudo systemctl start gunicorn``` and ```sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket``` gives the same error as before.

Comment: Now I have created ```sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket``` and filled up whit what the guide says but I still have he same error.

Comment: It appears the gunicorn.service may not be saved. Run `ls -lF /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.*`. You should see two files 1) gunicorn.socket and 2) gunicorn.service. I suspect you may be missing gunicorn.service as indicated by `unit file missing error`

Comment: Run: ``` ls -lF /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.* ``` Result: ```-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 360 Mar 24 21:30 /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service ``` and ```-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 112 Mar 24 21:14 /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket ``` I have created the .socket file 20 min ago but I still get the same error messages. So now I have both .socket  and .service files.

Comment: Did you enable gunicorn.service with `sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.service`? After doing that run the commands `sudo systemctl  is-enabled gunicorn.service`. Then check the status of service with command `systemctl status gunicorn.service`

Comment: ok ```sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.service``` this was the solution. Post it out as answer I accept it. Thaynk you you made my day. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the [Install] section in your service which means you needs to run the command `sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.service` to start the service on system startup.

Once you run the command a symlink to this file will be created in the directory `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/`.

Note that you also need to create the socket file named `gunicorn.socket` and need to enable the same. Once you enable, you can activate the socket by running the command `sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket`. You don't need to run the service as systemd will figure out the dependency.

You can check the status of the service with `systemctl status gunicorn.service`.

Comment: You made my day 

Comment: you made my day as wellllll thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2):

in my case, the server didn't create the`gunicorn.socket` file.
so, I had to create the file by myself and enable it.

go to:`/etc/systemd/system` and check all the available files and dirs by the command `ls`.

if the file is not there, try to re-create the file from the first by: `sudo nano ~/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket`, or `sudo nano gunicorn.socket`.

and then enable it first by: `sudo systemctl enable gunicorn.socket`, after the enabling do: `sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket`.

if everything works fine, you'll see the status of the file `gunicorn.socket` is active, after running the command `sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket` you'll see:

```
     gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor prese>
     Active: active (listening) since Fri 2020-06-26 17:53:10 UTC; 14s ago
   Triggers: ● gunicorn.service
     Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 1137)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.socket
```